# Summing the last five cells that meet a criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have column A which has a list of names such as, Bill Bob, John ect. Column B has a list of numbers associated with each name. I'm looking for a function that will return the sum of the last five numbers in column B that are associated with a specific name listed in column A.

These numbers will change as I add more names and numbers to the columns, but I would like column C to continue to return the sum of the last five numbers only that correspond with John, or Bob.

Thanks!

I'm using the sumifs function, however, it naturally just returns the sum of every number associated with a specific name, but I would like it to return the last five numbers only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` to filter the data that meets the criteria and then `CHOOSEROWS` to pick the last 5 rows then take the `SUM`.

```cpp
=SUM(CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(B:B,A:A="John"),-1,-2,-3,-4,-5))
```

If you want a formula that scales to any number of *"last values"*, you can use `SEQUENCE` instead of hardcoding the last n rows.

```cpp
=SUM(CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(B:B,A:A="John"),SEQUENCE(5,1,-1,-1)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the =SUM(CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(B:B,A:A="John"),-1,-2,-3,-4,-5)) Function and it returned the following error.   "CHOOSEROWS parameter 3 value is -2. Valid values are between -1 and 1 inclusive."

Comment: the FILTER is probably returning an error. Try to type `=FILTER(B:B,A:A="John")` in a blank cell and see what it returns.

Comment: Strange, it returns "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation." but there are at least 25 "John" cells in the column.

Comment: I got it, thank you!